# Class problems with Haskell

Tags: class, haskell, types, functional-programming

This time, I have these definitions:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Suit = Club | Spade | Diamond | Heart
  deriving (Show, Eq)

class Eq a => Eq (Cycle a) where
  step :: a -> a
  stepMany :: Integer -> a -> a
  stepMany 0 x = x
  stepMany steps x = stepMany (steps - 1) (step x)
    
instance Eq Color => Cycle Color where
  step color
    | color == Red = Green
    | color == Green = Blue
    | color == Blue = Red

instance Eq Suit => Cycle Suit where
  step suit 
    | suit == Club = Spade
    | suit == Spade = Diamond
    | suit == Diamond = Heart
    | suit == Heart = Club
```

My problem is that the line

```
class Eq a => Eq (Cycle a) where'='"
```

produces the error

```
    Unexpected type `Cycle a'
    In the class declaration for `Eq'
    A class declaration should have form
      class Eq a where ...
  |
7 | class Eq a => Eq (Cycle a) where
  |
```

Q: What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The example code doesn't define `Cycle` so I can't reproduce the problem reported. `Eq`, however, doesn't define a `step` function, so that's one problem.

Comment: The updated code still doesn't produce the error message given in the OP. The error message is: "Unexpected type \`Cycle a' In the class declaration for \`Eq' A class declaration should have form class Eq a where ..."

Comment: Unrelated: while in this case you were able to implement `step` using `== Red` and similar equations, it's usually better to use pattern matching instead. `step Red = Green ; step Green = Blue ; ...`. With more complex types `==` doesn't work, while pattern matching is a simple general solution to this tasks.

Comment: @chi Tried it. Pattern matching does not fix the error I am facing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `Eq` constraint on `Cycle`, nor on `Color` and `Suit`. You can just write the module like this:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Suit = Club | Spade | Diamond | Heart
  deriving (Show, Eq)

class Cycle a where
  step :: a -> a
  stepMany :: Integer -> a -> a
  stepMany 0 x = x
  stepMany steps x = stepMany (steps - 1) (step x)

instance Cycle Color where
  step color
    | color == Red = Green
    | color == Green = Blue
    | color == Blue = Red

instance Cycle Suit where
  step suit 
    | suit == Club = Spade
    | suit == Spade = Diamond
    | suit == Diamond = Heart
    | suit == Heart = Club
```

Comment: Why `==` and not pattern matching? (puzzled)

Comment: @n.m. I copied the OP code and made the minimal changes required to make it work. The OP is, IIRC, a Haskell beginner (nothing wrong with that - we were all beginners at one time), so I find it didactically appropriate to deal with the most immediate problem first. One thing at a time...

Answer (score 3):

First, use this to declare `Cycle`. This declares `Cycle` type class with `Eq` constraint. `class Eq a => Eq (Cycle a) where` isn't a valid syntax to declare neither `Cycle` nor `Eq`.

```
class Eq a => Cycle a where
  ...
```

Then, use this to declare its instance. You cannot write `Eq Color =>` because `Color` is a rigid type. The compiler will make it an error if `Color` isn't an instance of `Eq` while you try to make it an instance of `Cycle`.

```
instance Cycle Color where
  ...
```

The final code will be like this.

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Suit = Club | Spade | Diamond | Heart
  deriving (Show, Eq)

class Eq a => Cycle a where
  step :: a -> a
  stepMany :: Integer -> a -> a
  stepMany 0 x = x
  stepMany steps x = stepMany (steps - 1) (step x)

instance Cycle Color where
  step color
    | color == Red = Green
    | color == Green = Blue
    | color == Blue = Red

instance Cycle Suit where
  step suit
    | suit == Club = Spade
    | suit == Spade = Diamond
    | suit == Diamond = Heart
    | suit == Heart = Club
```

Comment: Same error persists.

Comment: Hmm, it worked well when I pasted the code above to test.hs and loaded it in ghci 9.2.5 (`:l test.hs`). You might want to add details about how you compiled or loaded it to your question.